# Any way to prevent "[LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor" entries in Docker logs?

Tags: docker

I am not experiencing a specific issue, however, I frequently see these types of Docker log entries coming from my `cm` and `cd` Docker services:

`[LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file information. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.txt. Error: 50`

`[LOGMONITOR] ERROR: Error in log file monitor. Failed to query file ID. File: \\?\c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs\log.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.txt. Error: 50`

According to logged issues in the `windows-container-tools` repo ([1](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/issues/34), [2](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/issues/125)), users speculate that:

1. It is probably benign
2. It could be due to log rotation (which happens frequently in Sitecore)
3. It could be due to concurrent file access

The log files in question are those which are persisted in the `/docker/data/service-name/` directories, which are mounted volumes to the services in the docker compose file:

```
volumes:
  - ${LOCAL_DATA_PATH}\cd:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\logs
```

I consider these log entries problematic because they create noise in my logs when I am searching for "error". Is there a way I can suppress these types of messages, or prevent them from happening in the first place?

For reference, the log entries appear to be coming from:

- https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/blob/main/LogMonitor/src/LogMonitor/LogFileMonitor.cpp#L1078
- https://github.com/microsoft/windows-container-tools/blob/main/LogMonitor/src/LogMonitor/LogFileMonitor.cpp#L2032